# Faster way to find the eigenvalues of a 4x4 real matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

I want to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenspaces of this matrix for self-study:

$\frac{1}{31}\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
43 & 9 & -23 & -61\\
16 & -19 & -10 & 22 \\
130 & 51 & -89 &-108 \\
36 & -4 & -7 & -59\\
\end{array}\right)$

I tried using the normal method of finding $det(A - \lambda I)$, but just these massive numbers kept coming up. I also tried using different block matrix formulae, but I ended up with the same problem. I wanted to ask if there was maybe a better more efficient way of finding the eigenvalues using some trick.

I know that the trace of this matrix and therefore the sum of the eigenvalues is -4, but beyond that suggestions are appreciated. I am not looking for a full solution here.

Comment: Suggest assuming integer eigenvalues, further guessing that one of them might be $-1.$   To   confirm the guess, define $M = A +I$   and use row operations to see if $M$  is singular, i.e. reduces to a matrix with a zero row.   I'm trying to get you to construct a Jordan Normal Form.....

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* It is not too difficult to compute the characteristic polynomial of your matrix $A$. It is given by
$$
\chi_A(t)=(t+1)^4.
$$
Let
$$J=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$
It is easy to find an invertible matrix $S$ such that $SA=JS$ by solving a system of linear equations in the entries of $S$. In other words, your matrix is similar to $J$, and you can read off all invariants.